# how to open RTF string to text area or editor in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to load the string below to the text area in MVC.

In contrast, WPF uses the `TextRange` control.  But I wonder how to do that in ASP.NET MVC.

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Droid Sans;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs20 Indonesia is a Southeast Asian.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in `MVC` there is no inbuilt `controls` that does this functionality.

You should roll out your own or you can use controls like [here](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/rich-text-editor)

The above link basically uses a `jquery` plugin to render a rich text editor.

Comment: thx for the answer. but I want to load the string="{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2" to the editor you give on the link so that it was readable.

Comment: Then you have to `roll out your own` because each control might use it's proprietary ways to represent the `style` information. So, it might have difficulties in understanding what is for eg, `rtf1` may mean to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only 8 years late, but if someone may find it useful, i'm leaving it here.

if you already have the text from the Rtf document, you may just use a single line:

```
string plainText = (new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox() { Rtf = rtfText}).Text;
```